# Bug in RSA encryption/decryption using CryptoAPI Next Generation (CNG) in Windows?

Tags: rsa, cng

I have written a code to encrypt and decrypt data with a hardcoded RSA key pair that was previously generated using the CNG. It is a simple program that simply generates some random input data, encrypts it with the public key, and then decrypts the resulting encrypted buffer using the private key. I print all the input, intermediate and output stages to compare whether the decrypted plaintext is the same as the original input plaintext, and repeat the whole encrypt-decrypt 10 times.

However, I am observing that in some cases, the encryption and decryption are fine, but in others, the decrypted plaintext does not match the input plaintext at all. Such buggy cases are completely random and arbitrary and there does not seem to be any pattern to these bugs.

Is this a bug in the CNG's RSA implementation or am I doing something wrongly?

Code follows:

---

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status)          (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)
#define STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL         ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000001L)

#define PrivateKeySize 283
#define PublicKeySize 155
#define InputDataSize 128

PUCHAR encryptedBuffer;
ULONG encryptedBufferSize = 128;


VOID printMem(PVOID Mem, int length)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%02x ", ((unsigned char *)Mem)[i]);
}

VOID Decrypt()
{
    unsigned char PrivateKey[PrivateKeySize] = {0x52, 0x53, 0x41, 0x32, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xB7, 0x50, 0x52, 0xDD, 0x58, 0xE4, 0x96, 0xAF, 0x91, 0xE5, 0xB2, 0x7B, 0x0A, 0xE6, 0xAA, 0x1F, 0x71, 0x8A, 0x66, 0xC3, 0xF0, 0x21, 0xD8, 0xE6, 0x2C, 0xD6, 0x25, 0x2E, 0x77, 0x3C, 0x61, 0x08, 0x1B, 0x69, 0xE7, 0x58, 0xDF, 0x3B, 0x07, 0xFE, 0xF1, 0xDB, 0xBF, 0xA6, 0x35, 0xDF, 0xC7, 0x49, 0x06, 0xC8, 0xDB, 0x74, 0x2A, 0xB9, 0xED, 0xB3, 0x04, 0x80, 0x75, 0x5F, 0x71, 0x2C, 0xD0, 0x14, 0x0E, 0x81, 0x18, 0x00, 0x5E, 0x34, 0x5A, 0xC2, 0x3A, 0x84, 0x63, 0xB1, 0x6B, 0x04, 0x21, 0x49, 0x7F, 0xE0, 0xF3, 0x52, 0x5E, 0x61, 0x43, 0xB1, 0x8F, 0x7C, 0xF2, 0x74, 0x29, 0x28, 0x69, 0x20, 0x36, 0xC0, 0x92, 0x17, 0x42, 0x99, 0x72, 0xE5, 0xE7, 0x82, 0xBE, 0x8E, 0x3B, 0x3F, 0xC9, 0x0A, 0xE1, 0xC4, 0x63, 0x68, 0x73, 0x1D, 0x67, 0x8D, 0xC0, 0xA3, 0xB4, 0xBA, 0xF0, 0xB7, 0xB0, 0x9B, 0xBB, 0x3F, 0xB8, 0x6E, 0xC0, 0x34, 0x1E, 0xA0, 0x01, 0x4B, 0x6D, 0x47, 0x73, 0x3F, 0xA5, 0x39, 0x05, 0x27, 0xD4, 0xD1, 0x38, 0x34, 0x32, 0x2C, 0x5B, 0x03, 0x5F, 0x16, 0x21, 0x64, 0x04, 0xD5, 0x19, 0xDB, 0xE7, 0x80, 0xDA, 0xBD, 0xC4, 0x1E, 0xAB, 0x61, 0xC8, 0x84, 0xDF, 0x54, 0x16, 0x77, 0x98, 0x9B, 0x90, 0x03, 0x83, 0xC4, 0x8D, 0x25, 0xB1, 0x32, 0x67, 0x77, 0x6A, 0x1C, 0x64, 0x2D, 0xFA, 0x9E, 0xB9, 0x26, 0xB5, 0xF8, 0x47, 0x4A, 0x9C, 0x35, 0x89, 0x5F, 0x12, 0x0E, 0xFF, 0x60, 0x87, 0x1E, 0x27, 0xC1, 0xC5, 0x7C, 0x77, 0x0A, 0xAE, 0x11, 0x37, 0xE3, 0x42, 0x9B, 0xAF, 0x9D, 0xBC, 0xC2, 0x52, 0xF8, 0x85, 0xBA, 0xED, 0x8E, 0xC3, 0x73, 0x04, 0x0A, 0x53, 0xD2, 0x1D, 0xEF, 0xA0, 0x6A, 0xCD, 0xBE, 0x93, 0x49, 0x34, 0x3A, 0xBD, 0xDF, 0x6A, 0x33, 0x25, 0x91, 0xFC, 0xE7};
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
    ULONG plaintextSize = 128;
    PUCHAR decryptedBuffer;
    ULONG decryptedBufferSize;
    NTSTATUS status;

    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlgorithm,
                                            BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,
                                            NULL,
                                            0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to get algorithm provider..status : %08x\n",status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptImportKeyPair( hAlgorithm,
                                  NULL,
                                  BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB,
                                  &hKey,
                                  PrivateKey,
                                  PrivateKeySize,
                                  BCRYPT_NO_KEY_VALIDATION);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to import Private key..status : %08x\n",status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptDecrypt( hKey,
                            encryptedBuffer,
                            encryptedBufferSize,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            &decryptedBufferSize,
                            0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to get required size of buffer..status : %08x\n", status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    decryptedBuffer = (PUCHAR)HeapAlloc (GetProcessHeap (), 0, decryptedBufferSize);
    if (decryptedBuffer == NULL) {
        printf("failed to allocate memory for buffer\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptDecrypt( hKey,
                            encryptedBuffer,
                            encryptedBufferSize,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            decryptedBuffer,
                            decryptedBufferSize,
                            &decryptedBufferSize,
                            0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed decrypt buffer..status : %08x\n",status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Decrypted buffer\n");
    printMem(decryptedBuffer, decryptedBufferSize);
    printf("\n\n");

cleanup:
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, decryptedBuffer);

    BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);

    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);
}


VOID Encrypt()
{
    unsigned char PublicKey[PublicKeySize] = {0x52, 0x53, 0x41, 0x31, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xB7,  0x50, 0x52, 0xDD, 0x58, 0xE4, 0x96, 0xAF, 0x91,  0xE5, 0xB2, 0x7B, 0x0A,  0xE6, 0xAA, 0x1F, 0x71,  0x8A, 0x66, 0xC3, 0xF0, 0x21, 0xD8, 0xE6, 0x2C,  0xD6, 0x25, 0x2E, 0x77,  0x3C, 0x61, 0x08, 0x1B,  0x69, 0xE7, 0x58, 0xDF, 0x3B, 0x07, 0xFE, 0xF1,  0xDB, 0xBF, 0xA6, 0x35,  0xDF, 0xC7, 0x49, 0x06,  0xC8, 0xDB, 0x74, 0x2A, 0xB9, 0xED, 0xB3, 0x04,  0x80, 0x75, 0x5F, 0x71,  0x2C, 0xD0, 0x14, 0x0E,  0x81, 0x18, 0x00, 0x5E, 0x34, 0x5A, 0xC2, 0x3A,  0x84, 0x63, 0xB1, 0x6B,  0x04, 0x21, 0x49, 0x7F,  0xE0, 0xF3, 0x52, 0x5E, 0x61, 0x43, 0xB1, 0x8F,  0x7C, 0xF2, 0x74, 0x29,  0x28, 0x69, 0x20, 0x36,  0xC0, 0x92, 0x17, 0x42, 0x99, 0x72, 0xE5, 0xE7,  0x82, 0xBE, 0x8E, 0x3B,  0x3F, 0xC9, 0x0A, 0xE1,  0xC4, 0x63, 0x68, 0x73, 0x1D, 0x67, 0x8D, 0xC0,  0xA3, 0xB4, 0xBA, 0xF0,  0xB7, 0xB0, 0x9B};
    unsigned char InputData[InputDataSize];
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status;

    for (int i=0; i<128; i++)
        InputData[i] = (unsigned char)rand();

    printf("Random Data is \n");
    printMem(InputData, InputDataSize);
    printf("\n\n");

    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(    &hAlgorithm,
                                            BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,
                                            NULL,
                                            0 );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to get algorithm provider..status : %08x\n",status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptImportKeyPair( hAlgorithm,
                                  NULL,
                                  BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB,
                                  &hKey,
                                  PublicKey,
                                  155,
                                  BCRYPT_NO_KEY_VALIDATION );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to import Private key..status : %08x\n",status);
        goto cleanup;

    }

    status = BCryptEncrypt( hKey,
                            InputData,
                            InputDataSize,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            &encryptedBufferSize,
                            0
                            );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to get required size of buffer..status : %08x\n",status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    encryptedBuffer = (PUCHAR)HeapAlloc (GetProcessHeap (), 0, encryptedBufferSize);

    if (encryptedBuffer == NULL) {
        printf("failed to allocate memory for blindedFEKBuffer\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptEncrypt( hKey,
                            InputData,
                            InputDataSize,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            encryptedBuffer,
                            encryptedBufferSize,
                            &encryptedBufferSize,
                            0
                            );

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))    {
        printf("Failed encrypt data..status : %08x\n",status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

printf("Encrypted Data\n");
printMem(encryptedBuffer, encryptedBufferSize);
printf("\n\n");

cleanup:
            if(hKey)
                BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
            if(hAlgorithm)
                BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);
}


int __cdecl wmain(
                   int argc,
                   __in_ecount(argc) LPWSTR *wargv)
{

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Encrypt();
        Decrypt();
    }

}
```

Comment: As a general rule, it's much more likely to be a problem in your code, than a problem in a common library.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug in CNG, it's an artifact of the way raw RSA encryption works. Some of the random values that you are encrypting are greater than the modulus of the key (the modulus is the value of the 2 prime numbers in the RSA key multiplied together), which means values wrap-around (if you set `InputData[0] = 0` you will see that input and output always match).

You'll also want to be either passing `BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1` or `BCRYPT_PAD_OAEP` to the dwFlags parameter of `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` as raw RSA encryption is not secure. If you use `BCRYPT_PAD_OAEP` you'll also have to supply a [`BCRYPT_OAEP_PADDING_INFO structure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible your problem stems from passing a `NULL` IV to `BCryptEncrypt` as remarked upon in Community notes at the bottom of:

[BCryptEncrypt function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375421(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -2):

I tried your code and if I make the generation of `InputData` static and not random such as:

```
ZeroMemory( InputData, InputDataSize );
std::string strInput = "This is just a test with a long long... very long string";
for( int i = 0; i < (int)strInput.size(); i++ )
{
    InputData[i] = strInput[i];
}
```

It does not return any error, I think there are problems with the extreme values of rand().